# How to customize the final view for a .navigationLink type of Picker? - SwiftUI (iOS 16)

Tags: swiftui, picker, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to change the final view of the selection by adding to it `.navigationTitle`. But it applies on both pages.

```
struct SomeView: View {
    
    struct ItemStruct: Hashable {
        var name: String
    }
    
    let items = [
        ItemStruct(name: "1"),
        ItemStruct(name: "2")
    ]
    
    @State var selection: ItemStruct? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center){
            List{
                Picker("", selection: $selection) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 2) { value in
                        
                        Text(items[value].name).frame(width: 40, height: 40).foregroundColor(.black).font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                }//End of Picker
                .pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
                .navigationTitle("SomeTitle")
                
            }//End of List
            
        }//End of VStack
        .onAppear{selection = items.first}
    }//End of body
}//End of SomeView
```

This code applies "SomeTitle" on both pages (SomeView and Picker view).

In final result I want to add Section for  ForEach list, make it searchable and apply "SomeTitle" only on final view. How I can do it right?

Comment: Please supply a [mcve]

Comment: This isn't _minimal_… anything to do with Core Data can be removed. Please update your code so it will compile for anyone trying to help you.

Comment: @AshleyMills You can compile this code.

Comment: What's `CoreDataList`? Remove anything to do with CoreData from your code

Comment: @AshleyMills But this is part of the context of my question. How then will anyone understand what `items' is? I want to ask the question in a way that is understandable.

Comment: Just use an array of `String` in your example code. The problem with the picker doesn't have anything to do with Core Data.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it much easier to help

Comment: So you can set navigationTitle by entering some characters here: `Picker("CHARACTERS", selection: $selection)`, but still don't understand how to set title for Section.